# Print out RDLC of ReportViewer as an image format

Tags: c#, image, reportviewer

I need to export a report viewer RDLC as an image that might be any image format.

When a set the the output format as PNG or even JPEG I got expection, as below:

[image]

If I try as EMF it works out, but not for others formats as JPEG or PNG.
Apart from that, How could I save this output image at the disk?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this link out it may help.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/703a2b34-dc35-4e32-8be1-9da4ea4e0e33/export-local-reporting-services-report-to-pngjpg-or-gif

Comment: are you add image in runtime otherwise add image property in reportviewer

Comment: @SenthilKumar How could I add image property in reportviewer?

Comment: @jcwrequests   Your link really helped me out. I just had to adapt the code, but used the same essence. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @jcwrequests   If you wish you can elevate your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could achieve the desired solution by the code below

```
var byts = report.Render("Image", "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PNG</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>");
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.png", byts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use the below code to download an image. or you can change your reportType to (pdf,word or excel) as well as the outputFormats to (pdf,doc,xls respectively)  for exporting reports as pdf, word or excel.

```
string reportType = "Image";
string outputFormat = "jpg";

byte[] renderedBytes = report.Render(reportType, null);

        /* Download File.....*/
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + "." + outputFormat);
        Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
        Response.Flush();
```